# Insert int variable into the class using LLVM PASS or Clang

Tags: variables, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I want to insert integer variable into all classes using LLVM PASS or Clang.

How to do this ?

For example..

```
class foo {
     int a;
}
```

I want to insert new value as below.

```
class foo {
     int a;
     unsigned int b; // I want to insert this.
}
```

How can I do this using LLVM PASS or Clang ?
 - I much prefer LLVM PASS.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use Clang for this, as LLVM operates on bitcode (IR) and the operation you want is very much C++ related, so why not exploit Clang's knowledge about the AST?

With [LibTooling](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) you can write stand-alone tool to do exactly what you want. More specifically, use an [AST Matcher](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) to find all C++ class declarations (*cxxRecordDecl*). You can then insert a new *FieldDecl* in your callback.

More info: [LibTooling and LibASTMatchers Tutorial](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html)